# where is cart success.phtml called?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

Where is the file: CartSuccess.phtml being called from when the users clicks on the "Add to cart" button on a simple product from within a category page?

I want to change the way that the Cart Success is being rendered so that it features multiple "pop-up" boxes

Comment: file come from magento root/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

Comment: Are you talking about the success message showing after adding product to cart?

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` to find out where the template file is injected. Run this:

```
grep -rni "cart_success.phtml" /full/path/to/magento/project/http/app/
```

Where `-r` is top recursively search the directories.

Where `-n` option is to precede each line of output with the number of the line in the text file from which it was obtained:

Where `-i` is to force grep to ignore word case i.e match boo, Boo, BOO and all other combination

Hope this will help.

Comment: kompletnie nic.....